# Can the covering transformation group of a 6-sheeted covering map have 12 elements?

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Can the covering transformation group of a 6-sheeted covering map $p : X \to Y$ have exactly 12 elements?

I suspect that the answer is negative, but I cannot see an invariant that shows this. We don't have any limitations on the nature of spaces involved (i.e. they are not necessarily CW-complexes, etc.).

Comment: If the cover is regular, no, because the cover is a principal bundle for the covering group. (Unless you're allowing many transformation groups, not necessarily acting faithfully; then yes, pick your favorite six-fold cover, multiply the deck group by $\mathbb{Z}/2$, and let the $\mathbb{Z}/2$ act trivially.)

Comment: You do not need regularity: Just follow the definition of the deck-group.

Comment: For this to work you need some hypotheses on connectedness (maybe your definition of covering already requires the total space to be connected). To be a little pedantic, $n$ points cover a single one, and the covering group is $S_n$. To be a little less stupid, you can consider the cover $$S^1\coprod S^1\to S^1$$ where each copy of the circle $S^1$ covers $S^1$ thrice. This gives you a cover with $6$ sheets and an automorphism group of order $12$. When a cover is connected, then there is a useful fact that tells us "two covering transformations that coincide at one point are equal".

Comment: @OlivierBégassat: It looks to me that in your last example the covering transformation group will have order 18 as it is the wreath product of $\mathbb Z_2$ and $\mathbb Z_3$.

Comment: @mathreader looks like you're right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit: I almost completely rewritten my original answer.

Let $p: X\to Y$ be a covering map of topological spaces. The group of deck-transformations $Deck(p)$ is the subgroup of $Homeo(X)$ consisting of all homeomorphisms $g$ such that $p\circ g=p$. In particular, such a group has to act freely on $X$, *provided that $X$ is connected*. Now, pick a point $x\in X$. Then $p$ is constant on the $G$-orbit $G\cdot x$, which projects to a point $y\in Y$. This orbit has cardinality equal $|G|$. Therefore, 
$$
d=|p^{-1}(y)|\ge |G|$$ 
where $|Z|$ denotes the cardinality of a set $Z$. Thus, for connected $X$, one cannot have $|G|=12, d=6$.

For disconnected $X$ the picture is much messier. Here is an example with $|G|=12, d=6$:

Let $p_1: X_1\to Y_1$ be a degree 6 cyclic regular cover (say, circle covering itself). The deck-group of $p_1$ is $G_1=Z_6$. Let $p_2: X_2\to Y_2$ be a degree 6 covering map with the deck-group $G_2=Z_2$. To construct such, note that if $H$ is the dihedral group of order $12$ and $H'<H$ is the order 2 reflection subgroup, then the 
normalizer of $H'$ in $H$ is $Z_2\times Z_2$ and, hence, $H'$ is index 2 subgroup in its normalizer. 
Furthermore, $6=|H:H'|$. Now, consider a connected complex $Y_2$ with the fundamental group $H$ and let $p_2: X_2\to Y_2$ denote the 6-fold covering map associated with the subgroup $H'<H$ as above. Then its deck-transformation group is $Z_2$.

Lastly, let $X=X_1\sqcup X_2$, $Y=Y_1\sqcup Y_2$, $p: X\to Y$ be the map whose restriction to $X_i$ is $p_i$. Then $p$ is a 6-fold covering; its deck-transformation group is $G_1\times G_2$, it has order $12=6\times 2$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate why the deck transformation group must act freely?

Comment: I was assuming that the covering space is connected, in which case freeness of action is a standard fact you can find in Hatcher or Massey. Otherwise it is false but the deck group splits as a direct product of deck groups of components.

Comment: Okay, I got it: the freeness of action follows from the "unique lifting property" for maps. it is interesting though if it is possible to get such an example for disconnected covering spaces. [For the sake of completeness, it is not always true that the deck transformation group splits as a direct product of groups of components: if components are the same coverings, the permutations are allowed, and we get a wreath product, not a direct one, as in the example of Olivier Begassat above.]

Comment: @mathreader: Yes, I was careless with this too.

Comment: I am not sure I understand why $X_2$ has deck transformation group of order $12$. If it is a $3$-fold cover, maximum what it can have is transformation group of order $3!=6$, no?

Comment: @mathreader: You are right, of course. See the edit.

Comment: Isn't it $p \circ g=p$ at line 3?

Comment: @Lano: Yes, I'll correct the typo.

Comment: @studiosus: the construction looks good to me, thank you! I was wondering if such an example exists with $Y$ connected?

Comment: @mathreader: I am not sure, I will try few more tricks to see if this could be done.